# Add image by pasting URL with media module

Tags: 8, media

In the screenshot, you can see I have the option to upload a video by URL. This is provided with the media module and the video embed field module.

Is there a similar module for adding images by pasting a URL. Or will this need to be a custom solution?

[image: example of media tabs so far]

Answer (score 0):

I found a module for your need.

https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_external